# Locked DNS settings on Netgear CG3700

Tags: router, modem

I’m trying to use a specific DNS server with the Netgear CG3700EMR-1CMNDS modem/router. I was able to do so using this exact same hardware a few months ago, so it is possible that an update may have changed things. The current firmware is V2.01.04. Resetting it to factory settings doesn’t help, neither does accessing the genie interface from a different browser. The only computer connected to it is the one accessing the web interface.

I tried to do it using the process outlined on [setuprouter.com](http://setuprouter.com/router/netgear/cg3700emr-1cmnds/dns.htm), with no success, as the box for “Use These DNS Servers” (seen in the 2nd picture on the website) is greyed out and can’t be selected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this for a home network?

Comment: Have you clicked the round circle to the left of "use these dns servers" to enable the text boxes for you to enter your own dns servers???

Comment: I have the same issue - the "use these dns servers" radio button is disabled.